# deep learning output data in keras fit method

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

if I have following data set and I want to predict all three feature How should I prepare the output data ?

```
 a      b    c
2265.0  8   21.3515625
2264.5  8   21.3515625
2268.0  8   21.3046875
2266.5  8   21.328125
2260.5  8   21.328125
2259.0  8   21.328125
```

I know Keras takes 3d input. Therefore the input needs to be reshape. There is a timestamps as well.So the output/label would be all except the time stamp in the dataset ?

Comment: Welcome Aboard, Please Add a bit more details so that others can help you for sure..

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about time-series analysis, your test data should be the three columns you want to predict, but shifted by some amount. So the first batch (e.g. first 5 rows) predicts the 6th row. Here is a small diagram showing what I mean:

[image: 5 rows predict the following row]

Notice that the timestamp column not in the target, and that we predict the three features in the following row, given an input of 5 rows.

Comment: meaning it will take all the values as well, not the labels only right ?

Comment: I understood that all the values in the following timestep are the labels... ? Is it time-series analysis? i.e. are the timestamps in chronological order?

Comment: yes, it is time series ( sensor data )

Comment: at the end I have to fit it to a keras sequential model